# Как добавить вкладки QTabWidget Python

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtabwidget

Как сделать так, чтобы за вкладку "Будильник"
отвечал определённый класс к примеру `alarmClockTab`.

Помогите пожалуйста.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QTabWidget, QVBoxLayout
import sys

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(544, 447)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 551, 441))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.alarmClockTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.alarmClockTab.setObjectName("alarmClockTab")
        self.deleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.alarmClockTab)
        self.deleteButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 360, 41, 41))
        self.deleteButton.setObjectName("deleteButton")
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.alarmClockTab)
        self.addButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 360, 41, 41))
        self.addButton.setObjectName("addButton")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.alarmClockTab)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 521, 341))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.alarmClockTab, "")
        self.watchTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.watchTab.setObjectName("watchTab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.watchTab, "")
        self.timerTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.timerTab.setObjectName("timerTab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.timerTab, "")
        self.stopWatchTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.stopWatchTab.setObjectName("stopWatchTab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.stopWatchTab, "")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Будильник и часы"))
        self.deleteButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "-"))
        self.addButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "+"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.alarmClockTab), _translate("Dialog", "Будильник"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.watchTab), _translate("Dialog", "Часы"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.timerTab), _translate("Dialog", "Таймер"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.stopWatchTab), _translate("Dialog", "Секундомер"))


class Tab(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(tabwidget)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Tab()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
введите сюда код
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(544, 447)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 551, 441))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        
        self.alarmClockTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.alarmClockTab.setObjectName("alarmClockTab")
        self.deleteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.alarmClockTab)
        self.deleteButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 360, 41, 41))
        self.deleteButton.setObjectName("deleteButton")
        self.addButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.alarmClockTab)
        self.addButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 360, 41, 41))
        self.addButton.setObjectName("addButton")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.alarmClockTab)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 521, 341))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.alarmClockTab, "")
        
        self.watchTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.watchTab.setObjectName("watchTab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.watchTab, "")
        self.timerTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.timerTab.setObjectName("timerTab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.timerTab, "")
        self.stopWatchTab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.stopWatchTab.setObjectName("stopWatchTab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.stopWatchTab, "")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Будильник и часы"))
        self.deleteButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "-"))
        self.addButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "+"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.alarmClockTab), _translate("Dialog", "Будильник"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.watchTab), _translate("Dialog", "Часы"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.timerTab), _translate("Dialog", "Таймер"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.stopWatchTab), _translate("Dialog", "Секундомер"))


class Tab(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):                         # +++ , Ui_Dialog
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)                             # +++
        
# +  vvv  тут ваша логика  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(self.add_row)
        
        
    def add_row(self):
        rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)

'''        
        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(tabwidget)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Tab()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо)